# How come the number likes can be a few orders of magnitude higher than check-ins?

Tags: facebook

If you look at [this page](https://www.facebook.com/PeoplesDaily), you will see (as of 2015-06-29) "852 people have been here" and "5.5m people like this".  Does it mean that 99.9% of those who like the page have never visited it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"XXX people have been here" means people who were actually at the geographic location, or have their photos or posts tagged with that location. "XXX people like this" means people who clicked on facebook "like" button. So, yes, it means that most people who "liked" the facebook page have never visited that place in real world.